# How to use GreenFunction for multifield PDE on finite cuboid?

Tags: differential-equations, solidmechanics

Is it possible to use `GreenFunction` for a multifield PDE?

**Explicit problem**

I want to compute Green's function with Mathematica on the **finite** 3D-cube $\Omega = [0,1]^3$ for the following PDE for the vector field $u(x) = (u_1(x_1,x_2,x_3), u_2(x_1,x_2,x_3), u_3(x_1,x_2,x_3))^T \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with some given $a_1 > 0$ and $a_2 > 0$ and right-hand side $r(x) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

$$
\underbrace{a_1 \mathrm{grad}(\mathrm{div}(u)) + a_2 \mathrm{div}(\mathrm{grad}(u))}_{=\mathcal{L}(u)} = r
$$

(this field equation comes from solid mechanics of isotropic materials). For simplicity, let's assume homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions on the finite cube $\Omega$, i.e.,

$$
u(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in \partial \Omega
$$

How can I get the Green's functions $G_{ij}(x,y)$ fulfilling
$$
u_i(x) = \int_\Omega \sum_{j=1}^3 G_{ij}(x,y) r_j(y) \mathrm{d}y
$$
for the three scalar fields in $u(x)$ on the finite cube $\Omega$ with Mathematica? Is this possible on V12.0?

I have not been able to find an example in the documentation and the following code does not work

```
Omega = ImplicitRegion[{
    0 <= x1 <= 1,
    0 <= x2 <= 1,
    0 <= x3 <= 1
    }, {x1, x2, x3}];
a1 = 1;
a2 = 2;
xv = {x1, x2, x3};
uv = Through[{u1, u2, u3} @@ xv];
Lu = a1*Grad[Div[uv, xv], xv] + a2*Laplacian[uv, xv];
GreenFunction[
 {Lu
  , {
   DirichletCondition[u1[x1, x2, x3] == 0, True]
   , DirichletCondition[u2[x1, x2, x3] == 0, True]
   , DirichletCondition[u3[x1, x2, x3] == 0, True]
   }
  }
 , uv
 , Element[{x1, x2, x3}, Omega]
 , {y1, y2, y3}
 ]
```